# Why does the picture compresses in my React App?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

So i was following a tutorial on youtube with full stack React app, and i added the picture in "AppBar" but unlike in the video, it compresses and shrink so it looks bad.
Here's the picture on the website:
[image]

And here's the code of the App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Container, AppBar, Typography, Grow, Grid} from '@material-ui/core';

import Posts from './components/Posts/Posts';
import Form from './components/Form/Form';
import memories from './img/memories.png';
import useStyles from './styles';

const App = () => {
    const classes = useStyles();

    return (
        <Container maxidth="lg">
            <AppBar className={classes.AppBar} position="static" color="inherit">
                <Typography className={classes.heading} variant="h2" align="center"> Memories </Typography>
                <img className={classes.image} src={memories} alt="memories" height="60"/>
            </AppBar>
            
            <Grow in>
                <Container>
                    <Grid container justify="space-between" alignItems="stretch">
                        <Grid item xs={12} sm={7}>
                            <Posts />
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid item xs={12} sm={4}>
                            <Form />
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </Container>
            </Grow>
        </Container>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: try removing ```height="60"``` maybe ?

Comment: i tried, but then the picture stretches on half the page, maybe there's a way to make it small without it compressing?